# iconv illegal input sequence- why?

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, unicode

While trying to convert a text file into its ASCII equivalent, I get error message that `iconv: illegal input sequence at position`.

Command I use is `iconv -f UTF-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT file`

The offending character is `æ`.

Text file itself is present [here](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0606461.txt).

Why does it say illegal sequence? The input character is proper UTF-8 character (U+00E6).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The file is encoded in ISO-8859-1, not in UTF-8:

```
$ hd 0606461.txt | grep -B1 '^0002c520'
0002c510  64 75 6d 20 66 65 72 69  65 6e 74 20 72 75 69 6e  |dum ferient ruin|
0002c520  e6 0d 0a 2d 2d 48 6f 72  61 63 65 2e 0d 0a 0d 0a  |...--Horace.....|
```

And the byte "e6" alone is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

So, use `iconv -f latin1 -t ascii//TRANSLIT file`.

Comment: How do find out which is the byte corresponding to offending character? I tried `hexdump -C file` command and got `0002b220  72 75 69 6e e6 0a 20 2d  2d 20 48 6f 72 61 63 65  |ruin.. -- Horace|` as output.

Comment: In what you got, you can see that the only top-bit-set byte (a byte whose value is ≥ 80 in hexadecimal) is e6. This doesn't correspond to a valid UTF-8 sequence (in UTF-8, non-ASCII characters need at least 2 top-bit-set bytes). In ISO-8859-1, e6 is the encoding of the character "æ", which corresponds to the expected text; so, this confirms that the ISO-8859-1 encoding (or similar) is used for this file.

Answer (score 5):

The file you linked appears to be UTF-8 *inside an HTML document*

```
$ file 0606461.txt 
0606461.txt: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

If you run it through an HTML-to-text converter first, e.g.

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT < <(html2text 0606461.txt)
```

then the UTF-8 fragment you appear to be having trouble with appears to transliterate without error i.e

```
Si fractus illabatur orbis.
Impavidum ferient ruinæ
--Horace.
```

becomes

```
Si fractus illabatur orbis.
Impavidum ferient ruinae
--Horace.
```

The `html2text` utility may not be installed on your system - if you can't locate/install it there are other converters including a python module.

Comment: No, the file is not encoded in UTF-8, but in ISO-8859-1. BTW, the `file` command says ASCII, but the reason is that it just looks at the beginning of the file, and the ISO-8859-1 character appears far away, at position 181536.

Comment: @vinc17 how did you find out the file was in ISO-8859?

Comment: @user13107 by looking at the encoding of the offending character: it is the byte "e6", not the UTF-8 sequence "c3 a6". Emacs also detected the file as being in ISO-8859-1.